# Minimal rank of a matrix with zero diagonal and nonzero off-diagonal entries over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the minimal possible rank of a square matrix, that:

1. is $m\times m$,
2. has elements from a finite field with $n$ elements,
3. has $0$s on its diagonal, and
4. has nonzero off-diagonal entries?

Comment: So you're asking for the minimal rank of a matrix over a finite field?

Comment: Sorry, I've put enter too fast.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: Don't know exactly. This is a thing for us to think after classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity matrix will have maximal rank $m$.

Comment: Oh, I mean minimal of course. Sorry

Comment: the zero matrix will have rank 0.